# Spring Integration Reactor configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, reactor

I'm running an application that process tasks using spring integration.

I'd like to make it process multiple tasks concurrently but any attempt failed so far.

My configuration is:

**ReactorConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ReactorConfiguration {


    @Bean
    Environment reactorEnv() {
        return new Environment();
    }

    @Bean
    Reactor createReactor(Environment env) {
        return Reactors.reactor()
            .env(env)
            .dispatcher(Environment.THREAD_POOL)
            .get();
    }
}
```

**TaskProcessor.java**

```
@MessagingGateway(reactorEnvironment = "reactorEnv")
public interface TaskProcessor {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "routeTaskByType", replyChannel = "")
    Promise<Result> processTask(Task task);
}
```

**IntegrationConfiguration.java** (simplified)

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow routeFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.executor("routeTaskByType", Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)))
        .handle(Task.class, (payload, headers) -> {
            logger.info("Task submitted!" + payload);
            payload.setRunning(true);
            //Try-catch
            Thread.sleep(999999);
            return payload;
        })
        .route(/*...*/)
        .get();
}
```

My testing code can be simplified like this:

```
Task task1 = new Task();
Task task2 = new Task();

Promise<Result> resultPromise1 = taskProcessor.processTask(task1).flush();
Promise<Result> resultPromise2 = taskProcessor.processTask(task2).flush();


while( !task1.isRunning() || !task2.isRunning() ){
    logger.info("Task2: {}, Task2: {}", task1, task2);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

logger.info("Yes! your tasks are running in parallel!");
```

But unfortunately, the last log line, will never get executed!

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've reproduced it just with simple Reactor test-case:

```
@Test
public void testParallelPromises() throws InterruptedException {
    Environment environment = new Environment();
    final AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final Promise<String> promise = Promises.task(environment, () -> {
                    if (!first.getAndSet(false)) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    return "foo";
                }
        );
        String result = promise.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(result);
        assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

(It is with Reactor-2.0.6).

The problem is because of:

```
public static <T> Promise<T> task(Environment env, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return task(env, env.getDefaultDispatcher(), supplier);
}
```

where `DefaultDispatcher` is `RingBufferDispatcher extends SingleThreadDispatcher`.

Since the `@MessagingGateway` is based on the request/reply scenario, we are waiting for reply within that `RingBufferDispatcher`'s Thread. Since you don't return reply there (`Thread.sleep(999999);`), we aren't able to accept the next event within `RingBuffer`.

Your `dispatcher(Environment.THREAD_POOL)` doesn't help here because it doesn't affect the `Environment`. You should consider to use `reactor.dispatchers.default = threadPoolExecutor` property. Something like this file: https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/2.0.x/reactor-net/src/test/resources/META-INF/reactor/reactor-environment.properties#L46.

And yes: upgrade, please, to the latest Reactor.

Comment: I'm almost sure I tried to set the default dispatcher via properties, I'll test it again tomorrow first thing. Anyway are you suggesting that I shouldn't use MessagingGateway for long processing concurrent tasks? Thank you so much

Comment: You can use Gateway with downstream ExecutorChannel, but you shouldn't use Reactor with the default single-thread `RingBufferDispatcher`. It is fixed, though, in the last Reactor-2.1.0, but hasn't been released yet.